# Convert separate digits into one whole number C++

Tags: c++, ascii

I need a little more help. I have managed to convert all my chars input from a text file into digits.
Example:
Input from file:

```
$1,9,56#%34,9
!4.23#$4,983
```

Output:

```
1956
349
423
4983
```

Now, I need to take those individual digits the 1 9 5 6 and make it read as a whole number. The output would look the same but they would actually be whole numbers. Make sense? I have to do this in my outer loop. It also has to be an EOF loop. So, I know I need to take the first digit and multiply it by 10 and add the next digit then multiply all that by 10 until I reach the last number. How can I write that in an efficient non-crashing way?
The input.txt file has the input stated above.
This is what I have so far...
Any help is greatly appreciated

```
/*
 */

 //Character Processing Algorithm

 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cctype>                                                                                                                         
 using namespace std;

 char const nwln = '\n';

  int main ()
   {
     ifstream data;
     ofstream out;
     char ch;
     char lastch;
     int sum;

     data.open ("lincoln.txt"); //file for input
     if (!data)
        {
        cout << "Error!!! Failure to Open lincoln.txt" << endl;
        system ("pause");
        return 1;
        }
     out.open ("out.txt"); //file for output
     if (!out)
        {
        cout << "Error!!! Failure to Open out.txt" << endl;
        system ("pause");
        return 1;
        }

     data.get (ch); // priming read for end-of-file loop

     while (data)
           {
           sum = 0;
           while ((ch != nwln) && data)
                 {
                 if (isdigit(ch))
                    out<<ch;

                 if (ch == '#')
                    out<<endl;
                 {
                 ;
                 }

                                  lastch = ch;
                 data.get (ch); // update for inner loop
                 } // inner loop
                 if (lastch != '#')
                     out<<endl;



              data.get (ch); // update for outer loop

           } //outer loop

     cout << "The End..." << endl;
     data.close (); out.close ();
     system ("pause");
     return 0;
     } //main
```

Comment: Is symbol '#' is the only separator of numbers?

Comment: Yes, '#' is the only symbol that separates the numbers.

Comment: Then the example of code in my post is all what you need.:)

Answer (score 1):

If you need simply to output all numbers in the standard stream std::cout (or some other stream as for example file) then you can use the following code as an example. I only substituted the file input for std::cin input in variable line. You can use file input instead of the standard stream.
Also instead of

`std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ),`

use

```
std::ostream_iterator<char>( out ),
```

and instead of

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

use

```
out << std::endl;
```

after the `std::copy_if` call.

Here is the example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( std::cin, line) )  // instead of std::cin use data
    {
//      std::cout << line << std::endl;

        std::string word;
        std::istringstream is( line );

        while ( std::getline( is, word, '#' ) )
        {
//          std::cout << word << std::endl;
            auto it = std::find_if( word.begin(), word.end(),
                                    []( char c ) { return ( std::isdigit( c ) ); } );
            if ( it != word.end() )
            {
                std::copy_if( it, word.end(), 
                              std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ),
                              []( char c ) { return ( std::isdigit( c ) ); } );
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test input data is

```
$1,9,56#%34,9
!4.23#$4,983
```

The output is

```
1956
349
423
4983
```

Or you can define the lambda before its using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( std::cin, line) )  // instead of std::cin use data
    {
//      std::cout << line << std::endl;

        std::string word;
        std::istringstream is( line );

        while ( std::getline( is, word, '#' ) )
        {
//          std::cout << word << std::endl;

            auto lm_IsDigit = []( char c ) { return ( std::isdigit( c ) ); };

            auto it = std::find_if( word.begin(), word.end(), lm_IsDigit );

            if ( it != word.end() )
            {
                std::copy_if( it, word.end(), 
                              std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ),
                              lm_IsDigit );
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the input file character by character. To check if a character is a digit, use `std::isdigit`. Then add the number to the back of a string.

If you need to convert a string to an integer, use `std::stoi`